# JavaScript data arrays doubling in value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to return data from a REST end point to populate a graph on a button press. If the button is pressed twice then the data is doubled, however, in this case I would like the old data to be deleted and only the new data to be displayed.

E.g.
On first button press this is the data returned:

```
{19455746: 28, 22254286: 83, 22255638: 136, 22808354: 34}
```

On the second button press this is returned:

```
{19455746: 56, 22254286: 166, 22255638: 272, 22808354: 68}
```

In this case I would just want the following returned on the second button press:

```
{19455746: 28, 22254286: 83, 22255638: 136, 22808354: 34}
```

My JavaScript code that the button press triggers is below, I've tried to cut this down to what I believe to be relevant, let me know if more code is required):

```
$scope.getDateRangeRoom = function () {
    $scope.data = null; 
    var obj = {};
    condata = null;
    ...
    $q.all(NexaService.getRoomDateRange(roomName, startDate, secondDate))
            .then(function (response) {
                for (var x = 0; x < response.length; x++) {
                    conData.push(response[x].data);
                }
                $scope.loaded = true;
                for (var x = 0; x < conData.length; x++) {
                    for (var i = 0, j = conData[x].length; i < j; i++) {
                        if (obj[conData[x][i].sensorUUID]) {
                            obj[conData[x][i].sensorUUID]++;
                        } else {
                            obj[conData[x][i].sensorUUID] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var sensorNameArray = Object.keys(obj);
                var sensorDataArray = sensorNameArray.map(key => obj[key]);
                $scope.data = sensorDataArray;
                ...
}
```

How can I make sure that the previous data is deleted and only the new data returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `condata = null;` with `var conData = []` line. You only need this variable within the function AND it has to be another - empty - array each time you call `getDateRangeRoom()`.

You didn't show where this variable is created currently; my understanding is that it's a shared state of scope. Even if you turn it into an empty array, there's a chance it'll be repopulated twice (or even more) on `.then` calls.

... and if, by some reason, you indeed this to be shared, clean it only exactly before the repopulation. For example:

```
.then(function (response) {
  conData = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < response.length; x++) {
    conData.push(response[x].data);
  }
  // ... there goes the rest
```

In fact, you can write this even more concise:

```
conData = response.map(row => row.data);
```

Comment: That is still causing the data to double.

Comment: Apologies, I had a lowercase `D` when I added your change. It is working as expected now. Thanks for your help!